# nutch 1.16 crawl example from NutchTutorial returns NoSuchMethodError on org.apache.commons.cli.OptionBuilder (Windows 10)

Tags: apache, nutch

I have been trying to run a Nutch 1.16 crawler using code example and instructions from https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/NutchTutorial but no matter what, I seem to get stuck when initiating the actual crawl.
I'm running it through Cygwin64 on a Windows 10 machine, using a binary installation (though I have tried compiling one with the same results). Initially, Nutch would throw an UnsatisfiedLinkError (NativeIO$Windows.access0) which I fixed by adding libraries from several other answers for the same issue. Upon doing so, I could at least start a server, but trying to crawl through nutch itself would return NoSuchMethodError no matter what I did. nutch-site.xml only contains *http.agent.name* and *plugin.includes* options, both taken from the same example.

The following is the error message (I also tried to omit seed.txt):

```
$ bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls/seed.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.cli.OptionBuilder.withArgPattern(Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/apache/commons/cli/OptionBuilder;
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.buildGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:207)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:138)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:59)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:534)
```

The following is the list of libraries currently present in the `lib` directory:

```
activation-1.1.jar
amqp-client-5.2.0.jar
animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar
antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar
antlr4-4.5.1.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
apache-nutch-1.16.jar
apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar
apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar
api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar
api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar
args4j-2.0.16.jar
ascii-utf-themes-0.0.1.jar
asciitable-0.3.2.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar
asm-7.1.jar
avro-1.7.7.jar
bootstrap-3.0.3.jar
cglib-2.2.1-v20090111.jar
cglib-2.2.2.jar
char-translation-0.0.2.jar
checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar
closure-compiler-v20130603.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar
commons-cli-1.2-sources.jar
commons-cli-1.2.jar
commons-codec-1.11.jar
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
commons-collections4-4.2.jar
commons-compress-1.18.jar
commons-configuration-1.6.jar
commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-el-1.0.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
commons-math3-3.1.1.jar
commons-net-3.1.jar
crawler-commons-1.0.jar
curator-client-2.7.1.jar
curator-framework-2.7.1.jar
curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar
cxf-core-3.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-xml-3.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-security-3.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-ws-addr-3.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-ws-policy-3.3.3.jar
cxf-rt-wsdl-3.3.3.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-3.3.1.jar
elasticsearch-0.90.1.jar
error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar
FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar
geronimo-jcache_1.0_spec-1.0-alpha-1.jar
gora-hbase-0.3.jar
gson-2.2.4.jar
guava-25.0-jre.jar
guice-3.0.jar
guice-servlet-3.0.jar
h2-1.4.197.jar
hadoop-0.20.0-ant.jar
hadoop-0.20.0-core.jar
hadoop-0.20.0-examples.jar
hadoop-0.20.0-test.jar
hadoop-0.20.0-tools.jar
hadoop-annotations-2.9.2.jar
hadoop-auth-2.9.2.jar
hadoop-common-2.9.2.jar
hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar
hadoop-core_0.20.0.xml
hadoop-core_0.21.0.xml
hadoop-core_0.22.0.xml
hadoop-hdfs-2.9.2.jar
hadoop-hdfs-client-2.9.2.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.2.0.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.9.2.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.9.2.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.9.2.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.2.0.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.9.2.jar
hadoop-yarn-api-2.9.2.jar
hadoop-yarn-client-2.9.2.jar
hadoop-yarn-common-2.9.2.jar
hadoop-yarn-registry-2.9.2.jar
hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.9.2.jar
hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.9.2.jar
hbase-0.90.0-tests.jar
hbase-0.90.0.jar
hbase-0.92.1.jar
hbase-client-0.98.0-hadoop2.jar
hbase-common-0.98.0-hadoop2.jar
hbase-protocol-0.98.0-hadoop2.jar
HikariCP-java7-2.4.12.jar
htmlparser-1.6.jar
htrace-core-2.04.jar
htrace-core4-4.1.0-incubating.jar
httpclient-4.5.6.jar
httpcore-4.4.9.jar
httpcore-nio-4.4.9.jar
icu4j-61.1.jar
istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar
j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar
jackson-annotations-2.9.9.jar
jackson-core-2.9.9.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar
jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.9.9.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar
jackson-jaxrs-base-2.9.9.jar
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.9.9.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.9.9.jar
jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar
jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.jar
jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar
jasper-compiler-5.5.12.jar
jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar
java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar
javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
javax.persistence-2.2.0.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar
jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar
jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar
jersey-client-1.19.4.jar
jersey-core-1.9.jar
jersey-guice-1.9.jar
jersey-json-1.9.jar
jersey-server-1.9.jar
jets3t-0.9.0.jar
jettison-1.1.jar
jetty-6.1.26.jar
jetty-client-6.1.22.jar
jetty-continuation-9.4.19.v20190610.jar
jetty-http-9.4.19.v20190610.jar
jetty-io-9.4.19.v20190610.jar
jetty-security-9.4.19.v20190610.jar
jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar
jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar
jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
jetty-util-9.4.19.v20190610.jar
joda-time-2.3.jar
jquery-2.0.3-1.jar
jquery-selectors-0.0.3.jar
jquery-ui-1.10.2-1.jar
jquerypp-1.0.1.jar
jsch-0.1.54.jar
json-smart-1.3.1.jar
jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar
jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar
jsp-api-2.1.jar
jsr305-3.0.0.jar
junit-3.8.1.jar
juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar
leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
lucene-analyzers-common-4.3.0.jar
lucene-codecs-4.3.0.jar
lucene-core-4.3.0.jar
lucene-grouping-4.3.0.jar
lucene-highlighter-4.3.0.jar
lucene-join-4.3.0.jar
lucene-memory-4.3.0.jar
lucene-queries-4.3.0.jar
lucene-queryparser-4.3.0.jar
lucene-sandbox-4.3.0.jar
lucene-spatial-4.3.0.jar
lucene-suggest-4.3.0.jar
maven-parent-config-0.3.4.jar
metrics-core-3.0.1.jar
modernizr-2.6.2-1.jar
mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre7.jar
neethi-3.1.1.jar
netty-3.6.2.Final.jar
netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar
nimbus-jose-jwt-4.41.1.jar
okhttp-2.7.5.jar
okio-1.6.0.jar
org.apache.commons.cli-1.2.0.jar
ormlite-core-5.1.jar
ormlite-jdbc-5.1.jar
oro-2.0.8.jar
paranamer-2.3.jar
protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
reflections-0.9.8.jar
servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
skb-interfaces-0.0.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar
snappy-java-1.0.5.jar
spatial4j-0.3.jar
spring-aop-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
ST4-4.0.8.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
stax-ex-1.8.1.jar
stax2-api-3.1.4.jar
t-digest-3.2.jar
tika-core-1.22.jar
txw2-2.3.2.jar
typeaheadjs-0.9.3.jar
warc-hadoop-0.1.0.jar
webarchive-commons-1.1.5.jar
wicket-bootstrap-core-0.9.2.jar
wicket-bootstrap-extensions-0.9.2.jar
wicket-core-6.17.0.jar
wicket-extensions-6.13.0.jar
wicket-ioc-6.17.0.jar
wicket-request-6.17.0.jar
wicket-spring-6.17.0.jar
wicket-util-6.17.0.jar
wicket-webjars-0.4.0.jar
woodstox-core-5.0.3.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar
xercesImpl-2.12.0.jar
xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
xmlenc-0.52.jar
xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar
xmlschema-core-2.2.4.jar
zookeeper-3.4.6.jar
```

This is my java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)
```

I'd also like to point out that, despite what another answer may have said, nutch 1.4 (or any other version of nutch for that matter) did NOT resolve the issue, at least on Windows.

Comment: You need to check all added jar files whether they contain the class `org.apache.commons.cli.OptionBuilder` in a different version. My first candidate would be to look into the added "org.apache.commons.cli-1.2.0.jar". If the mentioned class is contained, try to remove this jar file.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, I thought that I could work something out from the jar files but I was not aware of how to actually look into them. I ended up using 7zip to browse through the .jar files, then **jd-gui** to read the code within the OptionBuilder class files for several versions of Commons Cli. Bizarrely, none of them contained such a method. I'm left a bit stranded here, I'll try and see if the hadoop jars are to blame.

Comment: Ok, it's also possible that because of the modified class path another version of the ToolRunner is used which is linked to a different version of commons-cli. If you want to change the Hadoop version, you should start from the Nutch source package, edit `ivy/ivy.xml` and then build Nutch via `ant runtime`.

Comment: You did me a solid there, mate. Indeed, it seems that editing `ivy.xml` to reference hadoop 3.1.3 libraries did half the trick, with the other half being the same hadoop distribution being referenced by `HADOOP_HOME` and the corresponding **winutils** and **hadoop.dll** files dropped in the `hadoop\bin` directory. I'll update the answer below to add your info, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** The following answer worked for me, but I left the original one because it may still be useful to someone working with other versions of nutch.

Again, thanks to Sebastian Nagel, in order to get around the NoSuchMethodError, just edit `ivy\ivy.xml` to reference a different version of hadoop libraries, in my case I installed hadoop 3.1.3 and I also added the corresponding 3.1.3 versions of `winutils.exe` and `hadoop.dll` to the `hadoop\bin` directory referenced by `HADOOP_HOME`. Running `bin/crawl` and it seems to be working correctly.

---

**Outdated answer:** Okay, after working on the source code itself (courtesy of https://github.com/apache/commons-cli) under the suggestion of Sebastian Nagel, I was able to find the (very simple) implementation for the method (https://github.com/marcelmaatkamp/EntityExtractorUtils/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/cli/OptionBuilder.java):

```
    /**
     * The next Option created will have an argument patterns and
     * the number of pattern occurances
     *
     * @param argPattern string representing a pattern regex
     * @param limit the number of pattern occurance in the argument
     * return the OptionBuilder instance
     */
    public static OptionBuilder withArgPattern( String argPattern, 
                                                int limit )
    {
      OptionBuilder.argPattern = argPattern;
OptionBuilder.limit = limit;
```

Using `maven` I was then able to compile the code into their own jar files, which I then added in the lib folder for apache nutch.
This still did not completely resolve my problem, as there seem to be deprecated functions being used by the entire nutch framework, which will probably mean even more work under similar circumstances (for instance, right after using the new jar I've been returned a NoSuchMethodError over org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getInstance).
I leave this answer here as a temporary solution to anyone who may have also gotten stuck on the same issue, but I surely wish there was an easier way of finding out which methods appear in which jar file before exploring their entire file structure, although it may just be me ignoring it.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know that Nutch and Hadoop 3.1 are easy to get running on Windows. We'll update the Hadoop dependency in one of the next releases, see [NUTCH-2777](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2777). Are placing `winutils.exe` and `hadoop.dll` in `HADOOP_HOME` mandatory? We should add a hint to the Nutch tutorial then.

Comment: Yes, at least I have found it necessary on my machine (Windows 10) and while working with Cygwin. A small addendum: I also had to update `ivy.xml` to include the 2.10.2 version of the **jackson libraries** due to yet another missing method error when running nutch as a server (with the `startserver` command). Doing so fixed the problem.