# Nutch-cygwin: ERROR output.FileOutputCommitter - Mkdirs failed to create file

Tags: cygwin, nutch

I just started using Nutch on windows 10 with cygwin. When I run this command from cygwin "bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls", I get below error:

```
$ bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls
Injector: starting at 2020-04-22 01:05:45
Injector: crawlDb: crawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injecting seed URL file file:/F:/Academic/Spring20/IR/apache-nutch-1.16-bin/apache-nutch-1.16/urls/seed.txt
Injector job did not succeed, job status: FAILED, reason: NA
Injector: java.lang.RuntimeException: Injector job did not succeed, job status: FAILED, reason: NA
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:443)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:569)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:534)
```

When I check in logs/hadoop.log, I found below error messages:

```
2020-04-22 01:05:47,806 ERROR output.FileOutputCommitter - Mkdirs failed to create file:/F:/Academic/Spring20/IR/apache-nutch-1.16-bin/apache-nutch-1.16/crawl/crawldb/crawldb-1609992588/_temporary/0^M
2020-04-22 01:05:48,378 INFO  regex.RegexURLNormalizer - can't find rules for scope 'inject', using default^M
2020-04-22 01:05:48,589 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local456428503_0001^M
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in localfetcher#1^M
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:491)^M
```

Can someone please help how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried without Cygwin ? Java is a Windows program so Cygwin can not help it.

Comment: Which version of Nutch is used? See this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60789911/5953351 - it's required to install winutils.exe and the hadoop.dll, eventually, also to upgrade to a newer Nutch version (1.17 will be based on Hadoop 3.1).